# Hibernate Mapping for interface which extends List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible with Hibernate to have something like this:

```
public interface FooList extends List<Bar> {}
```

And then map this in a class using `@OneToMany`:

```
public class Baz {
    @OneToMany
    FooList fooList;
}
```

When I attempt to do this I get:

> Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements

Comment: why do you need to extend a `List`?

Comment: Have you tried simply with `List<Bar> fooList;`?

Comment: Because in Java generics are removed at compile time but sometimes it is convenient to have a precise type to reason -- at runtime -- that something is indeed a list of Bar, rather then just being a List (e.g. I can say `myMethod(FooList.class)`, but I cannot write `myMethod(List<Bar>.class)`). This is only for convenience I could probably change my code though if its not possible with hibernate.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299345/474034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this doc -> [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections) , only a particular set of collection interfaces is allowed. Otherwise a `UserCollectionType` would need to be implemented:

> Hibernate uses its own collection implementations which are enriched
> with lazy-loading, caching or state change detection semantics.
>
> For
> this reason, persistent collections must be declared as an interface
> type.
>
> The actual interface might be **java.util.Collection**,
> **java.util.List, java.util.Set, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet,**
> **java.util.SortedMap** or even other object types (meaning you will have
> to write an implementation of
> org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType).

Link references version 5.2 but this constraint is present also since 3.x versions.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`docs`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-persistent)

> As a requirement persistent collection-valued fields **must** be declared as an interface type. The actual interface might be **java.util.Set**, **java.util.Collection**, **java.util.List**, **java.util.Map**, **java.util.SortedSet**, **java.util.SortedMap** or anything you like (**"anything you like"** means you will have to write an implementation of **org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType**).

So you cannot map your custom collection until to write an implementation of [`UserCollectionType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserCollectionType.html)